# Upload data using forms, but only file is uploadable instead of the data

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-livewire

This is my blade.php code

```
  <form action="{{ route('file.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                    <div class="">


                        <div class="mb-4">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlInput9" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Breakdown date:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="exampleFormControlInput9" placeholder="Enter Breakdown date:" wire:model="Breakdown_date">
                            @error('Breakdown_date') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                        </div>
                      

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label class="form-label" for="inputFile">File:</label>
                            <input
                                type="file"
                                name="file"
                                id="inputFile"
                                class="form-control @error('file') is-invalid @enderror">

                            @error('file')
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>


                <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
        <span class="flex w-full rounded-md shadow-sm sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto">

          <div class="mb-3">
                <button  wire:click="store" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
            </div>

        </span>
                    <span class="mt-3 flex w-full rounded-md shadow-sm sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto">

          <button wire:click="closeModal()" type="button" class="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base leading-6 font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:shadow-outline-blue transition ease-in-out duration-150 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
            Cancel
          </button>
        </span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is my route

```
 Route::get("/uploadszz",\App\Http\Livewire\Breakdowns::class);
    Route::post("/uploadszz",[\App\Http\Livewire\Breakdowns::class, 'store'])->name('file.store');
```

This is my controller

```
 public function render()
    {
        $session = new Session();

        $data = Breakdown::where('Identification_No',  $session->get('idno'))->paginate(5);
        $dent = Fieldequip::get()->where('Identification_No',  $session->get('idno'));
        return view('livewire.breakdowns',['data' => $data],['dent' => $dent]);
    }


public function edit($id)
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $breakdown = Breakdown::findOrFail($id);
        $this->breakdown_id = $id;
        $this->Identification_No =  $session->get('idno');
        $this->Breakdown_date = $breakdown->Breakdown_date;
        $this->Breakdown_problem = $breakdown->Breakdown_problem;
        $this->Breakdown_parts = $breakdown->Breakdown_parts;
        $this->Description = $breakdown->Description;
        $this->Complete_date =$breakdown->Complete_date;
        $this->Action_by = $breakdown->Action_by;
        $this->Reviewed_by = $breakdown->Reviewed_by;
        $this->Remarks = $breakdown->Remarks;


        $this->openModal();

    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf,xlx,csv|max:2048',
        ]);
        $fileName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();

        $request->file->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileName);


        $session = new Session();
        Breakdown::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->breakdown_id], [
            'Identification_No' =>$session->get('idno'),
            'Breakdown_date' => $this->Breakdown_date,
            'Breakdown_problem' => $this->Breakdown_problem,
            'Breakdown_parts' => $this->Breakdown_parts,
            'Description' => $this->Description,
            'Complete_date' => $this->Complete_date,
            'Action_by' => $this->Action_by,
            'Reviewed_by' => $this->Reviewed_by,
            'Remarks' => $this->Remarks,


        ]);



        session()->flash('message',
            $this->breakdown_id ? 'Breakdowns Updated Successfully.' : 'Breakdowns Created Successfully.');

        $this->emit('fileUploaded');
        $this->closeModal();
        $this->resetInputFields();
        return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully upload file.')
            ->with('file', $fileName);
    }
```

Im trying to do a pop out form that uploads the data to the database and stores the file in the public folder. The blade.php is a pop-up modal using the @include method. When I use `submit  <form action="{{ route('file.store') }}`, only the file is uploaded. When I use `wire:click(store)`, only breakdown_date is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You need to check Laravel basics and Livewire basics and go through a couple of tutorials. Basically form and form action is used for submitting form data to your route and controller. Livewire doesn't use this technique and Livewire doesn't use `store(Request $request)!` You either Livewire bind properties and save them from Livewire component or submit a form to a route and controller.